# Whats the meaning of this C? int (*f)(int, int)

Tags: c

I am a bit rusty in programming, so I came here to ask what's the meaning of this line?

```
int (*f)(int, int)
```

Comment: `f` is a pointer to the function which takes two `int` arguments and returns an `int` (assuming you have a typo and actually meant to write `(*f)`

Comment: It looks invalid. Do yo mean `int (*f)(int, int)`?

Comment: yeah, typing error :P

Comment: thx a lot  Sergey :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use https://cdecl.org/ to translate thigs like that.

`int (*f)(int, int)` => declare f as pointer to function (int, int) returning int.

Comment: Really cool this cdecl... I've never heard about it. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Much appreciated :D

Answer (score 4):

It declares `f` as a pointer to a function taking two `int` parameters and returning an `int`:

```
       f               -- f
     (*f)              -- is a pointer to
     (*f)(        )    --   a function taking
     (*f)(        )    --     unnamed parameter
     (*f)(int,    )    --       is an int
     (*f)(int,    )    --     unnamed parameter
     (*f)(int, int)    --       is an int
 int (*f)(int, int)    --   returning int
```

Function pointers typically get used when you're dealing with callbacks (the [`qsort`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/qsort.3.html) library function is probably the canonical example) or when using functions in a shared or dynamically loaded library:

```
int (*f)(int, int) = dlsym( shared_lib, "foo" );
```

They're also handy for building table-driven code - I once wrote a utility to load and parse different types of data files from various scientific instruments and load them into a database, each of which had slightly different formats based on the instrument and type of data.  So I built a table that was keyed by instrument and data type, with a pointer to the appropriate parsing function:

```
struct parser_lookup {
  char *instrument;  // name of the instrument
  char *type;        // sample data, calibration data, etc.
  void (*parser)( const char *fname, db_handle *db );
} parser_table = 
{
  { "GRA", "DAT", parse_gra_dat },
  { "GRA", "CAL", parse_gra_cal },
  { "SHR", "DAT", parse_shr_dat },
  { "SHR", "CAL", parse_shr_cal },
  ...
};
```

then I had a function to search the table:

```
void (*get_parser( const char *filename ))(const char *, db_handle * )
{
  // Extract instrument and data type from the file name,
  // search the table and return the appropriate function pointer
  // or NULL
}
```

then in the main code I had

```
db_handle *db;
char *fname;
...
while ( (fname = next_file_in_queue()) )
{
  void (*parse)(const char *, db_handle *) = get_parser( fname );
  if ( parse )
    parse( fname, db );
}
```

That way when a new instrument got added all I had to do was write a new parsing function and add an entry to the lookup table - I didn't have to touch the main application logic.

Answer (score 0):

```
int (*f)(int, int)
```

`f` is a pointer to a function that returns an integer and takes two integers as parameters.  You can store on that pointer variable (if you prepend that statement with a `typedef` particle, then you are defining a pointer to function type, instead) a reference (by using just the function name, withoug the '()' parenthesis) to any function that takes two integers and returns one integer, and later call the function (that could be dynamically assigned to the pointer, so it is posible to change the function called) by using:

```
int a = (*f)(3, 4);
```

or the simpler abbreviation:

```
int a = f(3, 4);
```

(this will call the actual function for which you have stored its reference in `f`)